# Downloading a file from a website from a Cordova iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I have a Cordova app that downloads an image file from a website and saves to the local cache.  This works fine on Android, but not on iOS.  I am using Cordova 10.0.0 with iOS 6.1.1

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", 'https://www.mywbsite.com/image.jpg', true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(xhr.readyState);
}

xhr.onload = function() {
    
    var blob = xhr.response;

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.cacheDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {
        directoryEntry.getFile('downloadedFile.jpg', { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function (result) {
                    console.log("Success");
                };
                fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                    console.log("failed");
                };
                fileWriter.write(blob);
            }, function(e) {
                console.log("failed");
            });
        }, function(e) {
            console.log("failed");
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("failed");
    });
}
xhr.onerror = function(e) { 
    console.log("failed "+xhr.status);
}

xhr.send();
```

The readyState goes right to 4 and the status is 0.  I suspect this has something to do with WKWebView, but I am unsure how to resolve this.  The remote site is not running a script, just the direct image I want to download.

Thanks!
Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue.  Installing the plugin cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr allowed WKWebview to establish the connection and download the file.